# postgres query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql

I'm very new to pgSQL.

Can any one help with resolving this error?

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function prac_data.document_get_document_title(integer) line 8 at SQL statement
```

The script is...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prac_data.document_get_document_title(documentid INTEGER) RETURNS TEXT
AS
$body$
DECLARE
xmlText XML;
rawText TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT document into STRICT rawText FROM prac_data.document_table WHERE entity_id = documentid;
    xmlText := XMLParse (DOCUMENT rawText);            
    SELECT xpath('/inps_flow_document/@title', xmlText) as titleText;
    RETURN titleText;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'document_id % not found', documentid;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;


SELECT prac_data.document_get_document_title(1)
```

im using SELECT into (as can been seen), but perhaps I'm not using it quite correctly....

Comment: try changing this SELECT xpath('/inps_flow_document/@title', xmlText) as titleText;  to SELECT xpath('/inps_flow_document/@title', xmlText) into yourVariable as titleText;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prac_data.document_get_document_title(documentid INTEGER) RETURNS TEXT
AS
$body$
DECLARE
xmlText XML;
rawText TEXT;
titleText TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT document into STRICT rawText FROM prac_data.document_table WHERE entity_id = documentid;
    xmlText := XMLParse (DOCUMENT rawText);            
    titleText := xpath('/inps_flow_document/@title', xmlText);
    RETURN titleText;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'document_id % not found', documentid;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```